# Add background image into applet frame

Tags: java, image, swing, background-image, japplet

I am trying to add a background image to my applet, but don't know how to add.

Here is my code.

```
public class SAMmain extends JApplet{    
    public JMenuBar mbar=new JMenuBar();    
    public JMenu newStudent,viewtudent,markAttendence;

    public void init() {
        setSize(1366, 768);
        setJMenuBar(mbar);
        newStudent= new JMenu("New Student  ");
        mbar.add(newStudent);
        viewtudent= new JMenu("View student");      
        mbar.add(viewtudent);
        markAttendence= new JMenu("Mark Attendence");
        mbar.add(markAttendence);
    }

    public void start() {
    }   
     public void stop() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `paint` function

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {

        ImageIcon i = new ImageIcon("path");
        g.drawImage(i.getImage(), x, y, this);
    }
```

and dont forget to import `import javax.swing.ImageIcon;`

Comment: should i copy the image in the src folder ??

Comment: Now that you've broken the paint chain, nothing will get painted properly on the applet...

Comment: @M.ShamsTabrez copy your image in project folder only. and  in path write 'yourimage.jpg' if it is a jpg file.

Comment: 1) The `paint` method is supposed to exit quickly, and should not be used to load resources. 2) Loading an image using `ImageIcon` does not produce the kind of helpful error messages you might see with `ImageIO.read(..)` 3) Any override of a paint method should call the super method. --  OK - so 3 pieces of questionable advice in just 4 LOC.  That's not bad ..it's **atrocious!**  -1

Comment: i am prty new in java.....
i have written the mathod into the init() method but it didnt work

Comment: you should write that paint() method outside the init() method

Comment: one more thing, how can i cover the frame with the image ??

Comment: for that you need jlabel. set icon to the jlabel and then add it the frame.

Answer (score 0):

There are any number of ways this might be achieved based on what you want...

### You Could...

Make the content pane a `JLabel`, setting the icon to it...

```
public void init() {
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource")));
    setContentPane(label);
    setLayout(...);
    //...
}
```

### You could...

Use the `Graphics` API, for example...

```
public class BackgroundPane extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage img;

    public BackgroundPane() {
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/path/to/resource"));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return img == null ? new Dimension(200, 200) : new Dimension(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight());
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (img != null) {
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this);
            g2d.dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Then you could set it as you applet's content pane...

```
public void init() {
    BackgroundPane background = new BackgroundPane();
    setContentPane(background);
    setLayout(...);
    //...
}
```

The only real reason to use something like this would be because you want to process the image in some special way, like it's position, size, alpha etc...

This all assumes that the image has being packaged into one of the Jars of the application and is available at runtime from the context of the class path...